# How I can sum 360 raster files in a folder with the Arcgis raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator, statistics

In a folder I have 360 precipitation raster files and I want to sum them all to the raster calculator

Comment: Hi Juan, do you have any ability with python?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using and what you have tried so far with respect to tryi9ng to do this with the raster calculator, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform these calculation on a per cell basis using [Cell Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000). Specify the "SUM" statistic type.

[image]

Comment: Hi @aaron, that is true, but what I think is the problem is that he wants to do 360 of them and that would be tedious to put into the tool... perhaps. It would take less time to do it manually (once) than to write a script to list the rasters and feed that into a tool but if you want to do it a few times it would be worth scripting.

Comment: It may be more tedious to write a script to do the work. Adding the rasters is a couple clicks of a mouse.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good solution in one of the answers on this page:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/25945

```py
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1  
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')  
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = outPath  
arcpy.env.workspace = dataPath  
#create a list of rasters in the workspace  
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('','')  

i = 0  
#loop through rasters in list  
for raster in rasters:  
    print "processing raster: %s" %os.path.join(dataPath,raster)  

    #convert nodata to zero  
    out1 = Con(IsNull(raster), 0, raster)  

    #sum rasters together  
    if i == 0:  
        out2 = arcpy.Raster(out1)  
        i += 1  
    else:  
        out2 = out2 + out1  
        i += 1  

#save final output  
out.save(os.path.join(outPath,'sumRas'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is incorrect.  See this edit to avoid an 'expected raster or raster layer' error.

```
 if i == 0:  
        out2 = out1  
        i += 1  
    else:  
        out2 = out2 + out1
```